# Validate the client calling my Asp.net WebApi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net web api service which is called from a web forms application using jquery. I am using forms based authentication and the AuthorizeAttribute to allow only certain roles to access data.

I have a method on my web api .. Get which takes an id, I don't like the idea that an authenticated user could work out a URL and browse data from the database. Is it possible to validate the client calling the web api? So if I call the web api from my jquery code it works but if someone enters a URL in the browser it declines access?

Thanks for your help.. The web api is amazing! I just need to tame its audience.

Comment: There is a fair amount out there - google Authorization Web API - http://blog.developers.ba/post/2012/03/03/ASPNET-Web-API-Authorization-using-Tokens.aspx

Comment: Ok so use a token .. the code shown on that page shows how you would validate for a token.. But I don't get - how I get my token in the first place (on page load of my aspx page do I add the token to my response some how?) and how that is securely stored on my aspx page and how I use it in jquery without exposing the token to the world.

Comment: That post actually passes the token though the query string.. So I don't see how that solves the problem as you could just monitor the network traffic and craft your own urls whilst the token was valid.

Comment: See the [Security Section of ASP.net Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api) official documentation. It shows different ways you can control access.

Comment: EdSF.. I'm already using the AuthorizeAttribute, just because I allow a certain role access to a method such as Get doesn't mean I want to allow them to browse any data from that method in a browser. So if I have a GetCompany method and you pass an Id, I then validate the user is allowed to run the method, but I don't want them to be able to see all companies by hacking a URL in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use a api key that jQuery uses for invoking the Web API methods, and have a MessageHandler for validating that key (as it is discussed here, http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/implementing-message-handlers-to-track-your-asp-net-web-api-usage/). However, I think the Web API method should also validate the authenticated user has access to a given ID before returning the data.

Regards,
Pablo.